# User Authentication using REST

Tags: android, spring, rest, restful-authentication

I apologize if my questions seems to be repetitive but I couldn't find a answer for this yet.

I am building a REST based application using Spring 3.0 and plan to deploy to Google App Engine eventually. Now my clients could be Native Android, iPhone, or a Web Based Client.

My users need to login using username and password stored in server inside a persistence layer. Now say my Android client opens the app and login screen is shown is user. Now user types in username and password.

I know it would be a post and say my service endpoint is registration. So it would be something like

POST
/registration

Now I plan to put username and password in body of message in Json or XML format.  My question is "is this the right way to do it?" I am planning to make it SSL but how should I really send this sensitive info like this in body . I plan to return an OAUth token on successful authentication and use that to validate the user in all future services calls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have the right idea.  SSL should ensure whichever method you choose to send it in is secure.

Remember to salt + hash the passwords before storing them:
[web cryptography - salted hash and other tasty dishes](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/web-cryptography-salted-hash-and-other-tasty-dishes/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do I need to worry about any other security threat....

Answer (score 2):

Use the authorization header for sending the username and password information.  That's what it is there for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input.   Authorization Header- what are the advantages of using authorization header ?

Comment: @SaKet that's where HTTP intended to Authorization information to be put. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p7-auth-13